# Solution of given differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the solution of following differential solution:

$\frac{dy}{dx}+\frac{2y}{3}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{y}}$

I can't see any standard form in this? Any suggestion?

Comment: This is a Bernoulli equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

$$\frac{\text{d}y(x)}{\text{d}x}+\frac{2y(x)}{3}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{y(x)}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$y'(x)+\frac{2y(x)}{3}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{y(x)}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{3\sqrt{y(x)}y'(x)}{2}+y(x)^{\frac{3}{2}}=\frac{3x}{2}\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Let $v(x)=y(x)^{\frac{3}{2}}$, which gives $v'(x)=\frac{3\sqrt{y(x)}y'(x)}{2}$:

---

$$v'(x)+v(x)=\frac{3x}{2}\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Let $\mu(x)=e^{\int1\space\text{d}x}=e^x$;

Multiply both sides by $\mu(x)$:

---

$$e^xv(x)+\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}e^xv(x)=\frac{3xe^x}{2}\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Apply the reverse product rule $g\frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}x}+f\frac{\text{d}f}{\text{d}x}=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}(fg)$ to the left-hand side:

---

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(e^xv(x)\right)=\frac{3xe^x}{2}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\int\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(e^xv(x)\right)\space\text{d}x=\int\frac{3xe^x}{2}\space\text{d}x$$